# How to change sequence composer in WSDL to ALL

Tags: asp.net, xsd, wsdl, asmx

I want to make the value of sequence to ALL in an asp.net asmx web service WSDL.. is it possible and if so how? Google couldn't give much help regarding this.. so please help if anyone knows how to do this..

Comment: This discussion is telling about the values possible in the sequence composer but there is no info about how to do this [link](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/427658-removing-sequence-tag-soap-wsdl-schema-help-please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you want to do this? In general, `xs:all` is a bad idea.

Second, there's no good way to do it with ASMX web services or with WCF.There are bad ways, though. In ASMX, change your `WebMethod` to accept and/or return an `XmlElement`, and do the processing on your own. In WCF, use `Message` in the same way.

You won't be able to use the automatically-generated WSDL in either case.

Comment: I know it doesn't matter at this point, but this is probably why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205098/wcf-generated-proxy-is-order-dependent-and-service-added-new-elements-to-sequenc (adding a property in the middle of a host class can silently break consumer deserialization because `sequence` enforces declaration order)