# WCF generated proxy is order dependent and service added new elements to sequence

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, xml-serialization

We've built a client to an existing SOAP web service using WCF and C#. Recently, the web service was updated and our client stopped working. The problem as I see it is best explained in this blog post - [Interoperability Gotcha: Order of XML Elements](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/01/interoperability-gotcha-order-of-xml.html) by Yaron Naveh.

I'll borrow Yaron's example for my question. Originally, the wsdl looked like:

```
<s:element name="root">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element name="elem1" type="s:string" />
   <s:element name="elem2" type="s:string" />
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element">
```

The WCF generated proxy used explicit element ordering like:

```
[XmlElement(Order=0)]
public string Elem1
{
...
}

[XmlElement(Order=1)]
public string Elem2
{
...
}
```

In the update, a new element was added to to the type, but this element was added to the middle of the sequence.

```
<s:element name="root">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element name="elem1" type="s:string" />
   <s:element name="NewElement" type="s:string" />
   <s:element name="elem2" type="s:string" />
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element">
```

My WCF proxy cannot deserialize any elements that are ordered after the NewElement that was added.

The provider of the web service expected this change to be backwards compatible with older clients. Apparently, my client is the only one that stopped working.

Is this a breaking change in the WSDL?

Should new elements be added to the end of the sequence to prevent breaking existing clients? would that have made this backwards compatible?

If I remove the order parameter on the XmlElement Attribute would my proxies be better prepared for future changes like this? What do I give up if I remove Order?

Comment: The addition of newElement in the middle broke your proxy so it was a breaking change. What is the exact question, if this is fair?

Comment: I reworded the question a bit. I hope it is more clear. Basically, I want a second opinion on this. I want to be able to clearly explain to the provider of the service that their change was a breaking change (they didn't think it was). I also would like to offer them alternative changes that could have helped prevent this change from being a breaking change. I would also like some advice on how I can better prepare for these types of changes. I know I'm asking for a lot, but any constructive suggestions and feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that is a breaking change in their WSDL.  You are correct, adding the new elements to the end of the sequence would make it backward compatible.

If they wanted consumers to accept elements in any order, they should have used `<xsd:all>` instead of `<xsd:sequence>`.  And when they added the new element, it is a required element unless they add a `minOccurs='0'` attribute to its schema definition to make it optional.

They could also make their schemas more forward-compatible by adding an `<xsd:any>` element to the end of their sequence as a placeholder for future elements.

The main issue you may run into if you remove Order from your proxy is if they allow repetitions of elements with the same name in their sequence:

```
<s:element name="root">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element name="elem1" type="s:string" />
   <s:element name="elem2" type="s:string" />
   <s:element name="elem1" type="s:string" />
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element">
```

Without your ordering indicator, WCF wouldn't know which element repetition to map to which property.  If they're generating their XML from something like .NET or Java, this is very unlikely to be a problem since those usually turn arrays and Lists into a single parent element that wraps repeating child elements.

Another benefit of using `<xsd:all>` is that it disallows repeating elements of the same name, thereby avoiding this issue.  `<xsd:sequence>` has the "feature" of allowing multiple elements of the same name, differentiated only by their location in the list.

Comment: I verified this, and also, I tested against an old (.NET 2) web reference, see if this behavior existed then. The old web reference-style proxy class does not have this issue.  So the options, in order of appropriateness, are (1) replace <xsd:sequence> elements w/ <xsd:all>, if you can; (2) use legacy Add Web Reference to generate proxy; (3) use WCF and manually edit the generated Reference.cs class to remove the OrderAttribute with the "Order=0" (don't recommend it per @OranDennison's answer)

Comment: another follow up.....after replacing my wsdl to use xsd:all instead of xsd:sequence, i noticed that the nested elements that were arrays, were not deserialized correctly, and i was only getting the first item and not within an array.  So, as it stands, with the current WSDL file that I've been handed by the 3rd party, i can only use the legacy "Add Web Reference" way of creating a valid proxy class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for backward compatibility is to declare the complex type with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attribute as well apart from [Serializable] in the legacy webservice. By declaring as DataContract your client will get a proper deserialized parameters no matter how many new fields added to your complex type.

Comment: Plus when using DataMembers, you can explicitly specify the Order