# Is SoapUI overly strict for sequence Schema Assertions?

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui, backwards-compatibility

## Question

I am extending an existing SOAP-function call with an additional, optional, field in the the request and the subsequent response.
**I want this to be a non-breaking change**, thus have moved the field to the end of the existing sequence.

However, when testing for "Schema Compliance" using the existing Schema in SoapUI, the assertion fails with "Element not allowed..." for this new element.

**Am I actually introducing a breaking change, or is SoapUI just overly strict here?**

## Code for reference

Here's my original WSDL (for the response, condensed):

```
 <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..." xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...">
     <xs:complexType name="mutation">
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="addressLine1" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
           //...
           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="town" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
     <xs:element name="mutation" nillable="true" type="tns:mutation"/>
  </xs:schema>
```

Here's my new WSDL (for the response, condensed) (Note that the new UID value comes after the last previously existing element in the sequence):

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..." xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...">
    <xs:complexType name="mutation">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="addressLine1" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            //...
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="town" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uid" nillable="true" type="tns:uid"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="mutation" nillable="true" type="tns:mutation"/>
    <xs:complexType name="uid">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uidOrganisationId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uidOrganisationIdCategorie" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="uid" nillable="true" type="tns:uid"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's an example of the new response (condensed)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://.../GetMutationResponse</a:Action>
      <ActivityId CorrelationId="eaa2fb0d-0e9d-4237-909e-db025b6d7d74" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetMutationResponse xmlns="http://.../">
         <GetMutationResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..." xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:addressLine1 i:nil="true"/>
            //...
            <b:town>Couvet</b:town>
            <b:uid i:nil="true"/>
         </GetMutationResult>
      </GetMutationResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I would have expected, that the additional property in the sequence would be ignored by the "Schema Compliance" assertion. However I get

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.SchemaComplianceAssertion@1b1aa6e3
line 32: Element not allowed: uid@http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/... in element GetMutationResult@http://.../
```

## Notes:

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414654 and I believe I have circumvented the problem discussed there.

Context: This is a WCF web service, having a `[Datacontract]` attribute on the class.

Here's the class definition (condensed):

```
[DataContract(Name = "mutation")]
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("mutation")]
[XmlType("mutation")]
public class MutationExtern {
    private UidExternV1X8 _uid;

    // other properties
    
    [DataMember(Name = "uid", IsRequired = false)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "uid", IsNullable = true)]
    public UidExternV1X8 Uid
    {
        get => _uid;
        set => _uid = value;
    }
    //....
}
```

The service call returns a serialized instance of this class.

Comment: Are you talking about the performance of WSDL?

Comment: @TheobaldDu It's not about performance in terms of speed, but about whether SoapUi performs the Schema Validation as it's meant.

Comment: Have you 'told' SoapUI about the WSDL change?

Comment: @ChrisAdams No, as I would like to test exactly that: will old clients (with the existing WSDL used) be fully compatible with the updated version (with slightly expanded WSDL definitions)